# Restore Files from Sata SSD

Tags: ssd, gparted, restore

I am new to this forum, so if I make a mistake, please let me know what I did wrong and let me edit my question.

Basically, my friend had a laptop (a Dell Inspiron) that ran Windows 10. One day a couple months ago, the computer wouldn't boot. He did some online searching, and it turns out it is a problem that happens with his particular model often. He got a new laptop, but all of his files are on the SSD. I put it into a *much* older inspiron that I own and it said that the boot partition was missing.

I have access to a desktop computer (sudo privelages), the SSD, and a SATA to USB cable.

My computer runs Linux Mint 20.1, which is a derivative of Ubuntu (hence this forum). When I plug the SSD into my computer and open up Gparted, the drive comes up as `unallocated`.

I have done no formatting or anything to the drive.

My question is this: is there any possible way I can restore his files? I can run commands and post outputs, share screenshots, or whatever you guys need.

Comment: @user535733 I tried Testdisk and Photorec. Testdisk said it couldnt find any partitions, and photorec could restore 0 files. Does that mean that there is no way to recover his files? I dont think he used Dynamic Disks, but I am not positive.

Comment: You have exhausted the possibilities of amateur data recovery. If the data is truly valuable, time to contact a professional data recovery company.

Comment: @user535733 Alright. Thanks for the help anyways.